# Is there a way to have directives like ng-switch replace the div that contains the ng-switch with the correct outcome?

Tags: angularjs

For example, is there a way for:

```
<div ng-switch on="value">
    <div ng-switch-when="1"> 1 </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="2"> 2 </div>
</div>
```

to "return" the final form as simply (pretending that value = 1)

```
<div ng-switch-when="1"> 1 </div>
```

without the encompassing div?

Or is there another directive that can do this?

It would save me a lot of modifying CSS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using ng-if:

```
<div ng-if="value==1"> 1 </div>
<div ng-if="value==2"> 2 </div>
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/h8uap4NMJ9uGsFDy8Ck7?p=preview

Comment: Well, that was an obvious solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use **ngIf Directive** to add element into DOM conditionally.

**ngIf**

```
<div ng-if="myVar == '1'">Hello world</div>
```

This **DIV** will render only if value of `myVar` is 1.

Note : **ngIf** will create new scope. It won't work with **ng-repeat**.

For **ng-repeat**, you can use **ngShow** or **ngHide** directive. It works same as ngIf but it just add **display:none** by css class named as **hide**. So its better to use **ngIf**. **ngShow** or **ngHide** is expensive.

**ngShow**

```
<div ng-show="myVar == '1'">Hello world</div>
```

**ngHide**

```
<div ng-hide="myVar == '1'">Hello world</div>
```

By using this, you will not see `Hello world` but it will be in **DOM**